# R- ode function (deSolve package): change the value of a parameter as a function of time

Tags: r, ode, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a first-order differential equation using the function `ode` from the `deSolve` package. The problem is as follows: a drug is administered by a constant infusion rate at some times (infusion times) and eliminated in a first-order rate. Thus, the process can be described by:

```
if(t %in% Infusion_times){Infusion <- Infusion_rate} else{Infusion <- 0}
    dC <- -Ke*C + Infusion
```

where `t` is the time, `Infusion_times` is a vector containing at what times the drug is administered, `C` is the quantity of the drug, `Ke` is its elimination constant and `Infusion` is a variable taking the value of the infusion rate when there is infusion, and the value 0 otherwise. 
So, let's say we want to administer 3 doses, starting at times 0, 24 and 40, with each infusion lasting for two hours, and let's say we want `deSolve` to compute the answer every 0.02 units of time. 
We want `deSolve` to solve the differential equation for the times between 0 and 48 with steps of 0.02 times unit, for instance. So our vector specifying the times to the `ode` function would be:

```
times <- seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = 0.02)
```

The infusion times are given by:

```
Infusion_times <- c(seq(from = 0, to = 2, by = 0.02), seq(from = 24, to = 26, by = 0.02), 
                    seq(from = 40, to = 42, by = 0.02))
```

At first, I was concerned that the problem could be in the comparison of floating-points. To prevent it, I rounded both vectors to two decimal places:

```
times <- round(times, 2)
Infusion_times <- round(times, 2)
```

So now, hopefully, all `Infusion_times` are included in the `times` vector:

```
(sum(Infusion_times %in% times)/length(Infusion_times))*100
[1] 100
```

As you can see, all the values in `Infusion_times` (100%) are contained in the vector `times`, and thus the variable `Infusion` should take the value `Infusion_rate` at the specified times. However, when we solve the equation, it doesn't work.
Let's prove it, but first, let's specify the other values needed by  the `ode` function:

```
parameters <- c(Ke = 0.5)
amounts <- c(C = 0) #Initial value for drug is 0
Inf_rate <- 5
```

And now, let's write a function stating the rate of changes, just as required:

```
OneComp <- function(t, amounts, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(amounts, parameters)),{
      if(t %in% Infusion_times){Infuse =Inf_rate} else{Infuse = 0}
      dC <- -Ke*C + Infuse
  list(c(dC))})
}
```

For those who are not familiar with the `deSolve` package, the argument `t` of the function will state the times for which the equation should be integrated, `amounts` will specify the initial value of C and `parameters` will give the value of the parameters (in this case, just `Ke`).
And now, let's solve the equation:

```
out <- ode(func = OneComp, y = amounts, parms = parameters, times = times)
```

Let's plot the results:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(out)) + geom_line(aes(x = times, y = C))
```

This is exactly the same result we would get if `Infusion` was always equal to 0. 
However, note that if we were to mimic only a single dose, and we were to try a similar approach, it would work:

```
OneComp <- function(t, amounts, parameters){
      with(as.list(c(amounts, parameters)),{
          if(t < 2){Infuse =Inf_rate} else{Infuse = 0}
          dC <- -Ke*C + Infuse
      list(c(dC))})
    }
out <- ode(func = OneComp, y = amounts, parms = parameters, times = times)
ggplot(as.data.frame(out)) + geom_line(aes(x = times, y = C))
```

Here, we have made the variable `Infuse` take the value of the `Inf_rate` only when the time is less than 2 hours, **and it works!** 
Therefore, I am totally puzzled with these behaviour. It is not a problem of changing the value of a variable, it is not a problem of a comparison between floating-point numbers... Any idea of what could these be? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been struggling with the same problem for some time. I was trying to replicate IV infusion followed by PO dosing using the deSolve package rather than the RxODE package used in the original model. My solution was to make a list of infusion times and later extract a maximal value:

```
tmp <- c()
for (i in seq(from = 1, to = Num.Doses, by = 1)) {
tmp[i] <- (i * Tau) - Tau
tmp2 <- seq(from = 0, to = 2, by = 0.1)
Inf.Times <- round(unlist(lapply(tmp, function(x, Add) x + tmp2)), 3)}
```

Here, `Num.Doses` is set for 5 IV infusions. The `Tau` (dosing interval) is 24 hours, `0` is infusion start time, and `2` is infusion end time in hours.

Next I constructed a model, the full version of which is a multicompartment PKPD model from RxODE (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4728294/):

```
Model <- function(time, yini, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(yini, parameters)), {
    Infusion <- ifelse(time %% Tau < Inf.Time & time <= max(Inf.Times), Dose / Inf.Time, 0)
    C1 <- Central / V1
    dDepot <- - (Ka * Depot)
    dCentral <- (Ka * Depot) - (CL * C1) + Infusion
    list(c(dDepot, dCentral))})}
```

I got the idea for the `Infusion <-` line from Andrew Booker as shown at https://github.com/andrewhooker/PopED/issues/11. I modified his suggestion from `if else` to `ifelse` and incorporated a hard stop after the end of the 5th infusion with the `time <= max(Inf.Times)` otherwise the model would continually re-infuse. That also allowed me to implement additional non-IV dosing using an events table when running the model using deSolve:

```
Dose.Events <- data.frame(var = "Depot", time = c(120, 144, 168, 192, 216), value = Dose2, method = "add")
Times <- seq(from = 0, to = Tot.Hours, by = 1)
out <- ode(y = Ini.Con, times = Times, func = Model2, parms = Parms, events = list(data = Dose.Events))
```

When run using the full model, the output is nearly the same as using the original code in RxODE, which is more straightforward and "clean". The differences, as judged by AUC, were minimal with sig figs the same out to 6 digits. I am able to replicate the IV infusions (first set of 5 peaks) and also recapitulate the PO dosing (second set of 5 peaks).[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I came with after a while, I adapted it from Berkeley-Madonna in a similar approach as you did. deSolve is a very general solving package, I am not sure it is the best option for PK or PKPD problems

Comment: As said, please avoid `if`, `ifelse` and the like in ODE models, not matter if it is deSolve or something else, especialla with automatic time step solvers. It may work, but it definitely harms the numerics and will unnecessarily slow down simulations.

Comment: @tpetzoldt, I agree avoiding `if` and `ifelse` speeds up execution. In this case, performance between deSolve and RxODE was comparable (per human time) with 0.15 vs 0.01 sec, respectively. However, a PopPK simulation with 100 subjects (variable CL and V1) using the same dosing scheme took 15 vs 0.5 sec, respectively. RxODE compiles the model and avoids the `if`, `ifelse`, but numerical results are equivalent. Per your advice about using forcing functions, I'm not R savy enough to write the necessary code.

Comment: It is also possible (and well documented) to use compiled code with **deSolve**, here is [one example](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-compiled/deSolve-compiled.html). Some benchmarks showed, that performance is then comparable to pure C or Fortran implementation. However, nothing speaks against the use of **RxODE** if it fits your demands. I really appreciate to have the choice between alternative packages.

Comment: Indeed, R provides much flexibility among its many packages. I certainly appreciate all your effort @tpetzoldt for working on deSolve since it's my preference for fitting ODEs. I was finally able to code and execute a forcing function for this problem based on the tutorial link you posted. As with anything, a little patience (with a lot of trial and error) goes a long way.

Answer (score 5):

Most solvers of **deSolve** use an automatic internal time step, that adjusts itself, depending on the roughness or smoothness of the system. The use of `if` statements or `if()`functions in the model function is not a good idea for two reasons: (i) the time steps may not be hit exactly and (2) the model function (i.e. the derivative) should ideally be [continuous and differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) and avoid step-wise behavior, even if the solvers are quite robust in such cases.

The **deSolve** package provides are two approaches for your problem: "forcing functions" and "events". Both have their pros and cons, but "events" are especially useful if the time for the "event" (e.g. an injection) is very short, compared to the integration time step.

More about this can be found in the **deSolve** help pages `?forcings` and `?events`, in [deSolve: Forcing functions and Events](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html) from the useR!2017 conference, and in the [slides](http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/tutorial.pdf)  from userR!2014.

Please check if the following works for you:

```
library("deSolve")

OneComp <- function(t, y, parms){
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    dC <- -Ke * C
    list(c(dC))
  })
}

eventfunc <- function(t, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)),{
    C + Inf_rate
  })
}

parms <- c(Ke = 0.5, Inf_rate = 5)

y0 <- c(C = 0)            # Initial value for drug is 0

Infusion_times <- c(seq(from =  0, to =  2, by = 0.02), 
                    seq(from = 24, to = 26, by = 0.02), 
                    seq(from = 40, to = 42, by = 0.02))

# time step can be made bigger to speedup simulation
times <- round(seq(from = 0, to = 48, by = .1) , 2)

# check that all events are in 'times', but no duplicates
# this check is also done by the solver and may print a warning
# to ensure that the user is very careful with this
unique_times <- cleanEventTimes(times, Infusion_times)
times        <- sort(c(unique_times, Infusion_times))

out <- ode(func = OneComp, y = y0, parms = parms, times = times, 
           events = list(func = eventfunc, time = Infusion_times))

plot(out)
rug(Infusion_times)
```

The two `cleanEventTimes` lines are one possible approach for ensuring that all event times are hit by the simulation. It is normally done automatically by the solver and may issue a warning to remind the user to be very careful with this.

I used "base" plot and `rug` to indicate injection times.

I wonder somewhat about the terms `Infusion_times` and `Inf_rate`. In an event-based approach, an "amount" is added to the state variable C at discrete time points, while a "rate" would indicate continuous addition within a **time interval**. This is often called a forcing function.

A forcing function would be even simpler and is numerically better.