# R - deSolve package (ode function): change a matrix of parameters in SIR model according to time

Tags: r, ode

I am trying to simulate the transmission of viruses in a population using the function `ode` from the `deSolve` package. The basic of my model is a SIR model and I posted a much simpler demo of my model here, which consists of only three states **S(susceptible), I(infectious) and R(recovered)**. Each state is represented by a **m*n matrix** in my code, since I have **m age groups** and **n subpopulations** in my population.

The problem is: during the simulation period, there will be several vaccination activities that transfer people in state **S** to state **I**. Each vaccination activity is characterized by a **begin date**, an **end date**, its **coverage rate** and **duration**. What I want to do is once the **time t** falls into the interval of **begin date** and **end date** of one vaccination activity, the code calculates the **effective vaccination rate** (also a **m*n** matrix, based on **coverage rate** and **duration**) and times it with **S** (**m*n** matrix), to get a matrix of people transited to state **I**. Right now, I am using `if()` to decide if **time t** is between a **begin date** and a **end date**:

```
#initialize the matrix of effective vaccination rate 
irrate_matrix = matrix(data = rep(0, m*n), nrow = m, ncol = n) 

for (i in 1:length(tbegin)){
  if (t>=tbegin[i] & t<=tend[i]){
    for (j in 1:n){
      irrate_matrix[, j] = -log(1-covir[(j-1)*length(tbegin)+i])/duration[i]
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `irrate_matrix` is the **m*n effective vaccination rate matrix**, `m = 2` is the number of **age groups**, `n = 2` is the number of **subpopulations**, `tbegin = c(5, 20, 35)` is the **begin date** of 3 vaccination activities, `tend = c(8, 23, 38)` is the **end date** of 3 vaccination activities, `covir  = c(0.35, 0.25, 0.25, 0.225, 0.18, 0.13)` is the **coverage rate** of each vaccination for each subpopulation (e.g., `covir[1] = 0.35` is the **coverage rate** of the first vaccination for **subpopulation1**, while `covir[4] = 0.225` is the **coverage rate** of the first vaccination for **subpopulation2**) and `duration = c(4, 4, 4)` is the duration of each vaccination (in days).

After calculating `irrate_matrix`, I take it into derivatives and therefore I have:

```
dS = as.matrix(b*N) - as.matrix(irrate_matrix*S) - as.matrix(mu*S)
dI = as.matrix(irrate_matrix*S) - as.matrix(gammaS*I) - as.matrix(mu*I)
dR = as.matrix(gammaS*I) - as.matrix(mu*R)
```

I want to do a simulation from day 0 to day 50, by 1-day step, thus:

```
times = seq(0, 50, 1)
```

**The current issue with my code is**: every time the **time t** comes to a time point close to a `tbegin[i]` or `tend[i]`, the simulation becomes much slower since it iterates at this time point for much more rounds than at any other time point. For example, once the **time t** comes to `tbegin[1] = 5`, the model iterates at time point 5 for many rounds. I attached screenshots from printing out those iterations ([screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB7BK.png) and [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THKbR.png)). I find this is why my bigger model takes a very long running time now.

I have tried using the "events" function of `deSolve` mentioned by tpetzoldt in this question [stackoverflow: change the value of a parameter as a function of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484483/r-ode-function-desolve-package-change-the-value-of-a-parameter-as-a-function/61487829#61487829). However, I found it's inconvenient for me to change a matrix of parameters and change it every time there is a vaccination activity.

I am looking for solutions regarding:

- How to change my `irrate_matrix` to non-zero matrix when there is a vaccination activity and let it be zero matrix when there is no vaccination? (it has to be calculated for each vaccination)
- At the same time, how to make the code run faster by avoiding iterating at any `tbegin[i]` or `tend[i]` for many rounds? (I think I should not use `if()` but I do not know what I should do with my case)
- If I need to use "forcing" or "events" function, could you please also tell me how to have multiple "forcing"/"events" in the model? Right now, I have had an "events" used in my bigger model to introduce a virus to the population, as:

```
virusevents = data.frame(var = "I1", time = 2, value = 1, method = "add")
```

Any good idea is welcome and directly providing some codes is much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

For reference, I post the whole demo here:

```
library(deSolve)

##################################
###(1) define the sir function####
##################################

sir_basic <- function (t, x, params) 
{ # retrieve initial states
  S = matrix(data = x[(0*m*n+1):(1*m*n)], nrow = m, ncol = n)
  I = matrix(data = x[(1*m*n+1):(2*m*n)], nrow = m, ncol = n)
  R = matrix(data = x[(2*m*n+1):(3*m*n)], nrow = m, ncol = n)
  
  with(as.list(params), {
    N = as.matrix(S + I + R) 
    
    # print out current iteration
    print(paste0("Total population at time ", t, " is ", sum(N)))
    
    # calculate irrate_matrix by checking time t
    irrate_matrix = matrix(data = rep(0, m*n), nrow = m, ncol = n)
    for (i in 1:length(tbegin)){
      if (t>=tbegin[i] & t<=tend[i]){
        for (j in 1:n){
          irrate_matrix[, j] = -log(1-covir[(j-1)*length(tbegin)+i])/duration[i]
        }
      }
    }
    
    # derivatives
    dS = as.matrix(b*N) - as.matrix(irrate_matrix*S) - as.matrix(mu*S)
    dI = as.matrix(irrate_matrix*S) - as.matrix(gammaS*I) - as.matrix(mu*I)
    dR = as.matrix(gammaS*I) - as.matrix(mu*R)
    derivatives <- c(dS, dI, dR)
    list(derivatives)
  })
}

##################################
###(2) characterize parameters####
##################################

m = 2 # the number of age groups
n = 2 # the number of sub-populations

tbegin = c(5, 20, 35) # begin dates
tend = c(8, 23, 38) # end dates
duration = c(4, 4, 4) # duration
covir = c(0.35, 0.25, 0.25, 0.225, 0.18, 0.13) # coverage rates

b = 0.0006 # daily birth rate
mu = 0.0006 # daily death rate
gammaS = 0.05 # transition rate from I to R

parameters = c(m = m, n = n,
               tbegin = tbegin, tend = tend, duration = duration, covir = covir,
               b = b, mu = mu, gammaS = gammaS)

##################################
#######(3) initial states ########
##################################

inits = c(
  S = c(20000, 40000, 10000, 20000),
  I = rep(0, m*n),
  R = rep(0, m*n)
)

##################################
#######(4) run simulations########
##################################

times = seq(0, 50, 1)

traj <- ode(func  = sir_basic, 
            y = inits,
            parms = parameters,
            times = times)

plot(traj)
```

Comment: The observation, that in regions of sudden changes more iterations are needed describes normal behavior. A system of differential equations is continuous by definition, so if you add a discrete step, you stresstest the solver. It tries then hard to approximate the discontinuity and does not break -- showing that it is quite robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element wise operations are the same for matrices and vectors, so the `as.matrix` conversions are redundant, as no *true* matrix multiplication is used. Same with the `rep`: the zero is recycled anyway.

In effect, CPU time reduces already to 50%. In contrast, use of an external forcing with `approxTime` instead of the inner `if` and `for` made the model slower (not shown).

### Simplified code

```
sir_basic2 <- function (t, x, params)
{ # retrieve initial states
  S = x[(0*m*n+1):(1*m*n)]
  I = x[(1*m*n+1):(2*m*n)]
  R = x[(2*m*n+1):(3*m*n)]

  with(as.list(params), {
    N = S + I + R

    # print out current iteration
    #print(paste0("Total population at time ", t, " is ", sum(N)))

    # calculate irrate_matrix by checking time t
    irrate_matrix = matrix(data = 0, nrow = m, ncol = n)
    for (i in 1:length(tbegin)){
      if (t >= tbegin[i] & t <= tend[i]){
        for (j in 1:n){
          irrate_matrix[, j] = -log(1-covir[(j-1) * length(tbegin)+i])/duration[i]
        }
      }
    }

    # derivatives
    dS = b*N - irrate_matrix*S - mu*S
    dI = irrate_matrix*S - gammaS*I - mu*I
    dR = gammaS*I - mu*R
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  })
}
```

### Benchmark

Each model version is run 10 times. Model `sir_basic` is the original implementation, where `print` line was disabled for a fair comparison.

```
system.time(
  for(i in 1:10)
    traj <- ode(func  = sir_basic,
            y = inits,
            parms = parameters,
            times = times)
)

system.time(
  for(i in 1:10)
    traj2 <- ode(func  = sir_basic2,
            y = inits,
            parms = parameters,
            times = times)
)

plot(traj, traj2)
summary(traj - traj2)
```

I observed another considerable speedup, when I use `method="adams"` instead of the default `lsoda` solver, but this may differ for your full model.

Comment: ... and reduced precision may again double simulation speed: `atol=1e-2, rtol=1e-4`. This is possible, because the absolute values of state variables are big.

Comment: Hi @tpetzoldt, thanks for your answer and comment! I have a few follow-up questions: (1) You mentioned that using an external forcing function was slower than the inner `if` and `for`. But did you suggest that using forcing/events function with deSolve was better than `if`? (2) I am not sure the reduced precision is for what? For state variables? How to reduce the precision? And what are `atol` and `rtol`? I am sorry I am kind of new to this area. Could you please offer more details for this point? Thank you!

Comment: Also, could you please show me the code of using external forcing if it's convenient for you? Thank you.

Comment: **Tolerances:** Reduced tolerance is for the state variables. Relative tolerance (rtol) is independent of the scale of states while `atol` should reflect the magnitude of the states. One way is to re-scale state variables, so that they are in a range of, say, 0.001 to 1000, this is what I recommend my students. The way is to adapt at least atol, so that it is not too many orders of magnitude lower than the states. `rtol`and `atol`can also be vectors if magnitude of states are different.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused about `atol` and `rtol`. Are they parameters of `ode`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Yo find it in the docs. See package vignette or the [tutorial slides](http://desolve.r-forge.r-project.org/user2014/tutorial.pdf), pages 23 and 33, or the [R Journal paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Soetaert~et~al.pdf).