# How to implement a system in deSolve, R, with N equations a N+m parameters?

Tags: r, desolve

I am coding a SIR model in a metapopulation in R, I want to integrate the systema and for that I am using de deSolve with C compiled code, I have used this before but in the case having a few parameters, now I would have Nxm parameters where N is the dimension of the system,so I would like that

```
/* file age3classp.c */
#include <R.h>
static double parms[3];
static double forc[1];

#define N parms[0]
#define N1 parms[1]
#define gam3 parms[2]
```

That this parms are vector or matrix NxN
It is posible?

In C my model will be of the form:

```
# SIR metapopulation model:
SIR <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    dS = c()
    dI = c()
    dR = c()
    for(i in c(1:dim)){
      dS[i] <- delta_N[i]*(S[i]+I[i]+R[i])
      dI[i] <- 10
      dR[i] <- 10
    }
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  }) 
}

population <- c(S <- matrix(100,ncol=N,nrow =1 ), I <- matrix(10,ncol=N,nrow =1 ),
                R <- matrix(0,ncol=N,nrow =1 ))
z <- ode(population, times, SIR, parameters)
```

In this way it does not recognise S[i] or the others as variables just as initial condition values.

How can I do in order to recognise it as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, and there are different ways to do it, depending on your C programming skills. The easiest is to put both states and parameters in two long vectors and then split it at the C level using numbered parameter and variable indices. The equations are then formulated as `for`-loops.

To improve readability, it is also possible to use

1. preprocessor constants for the indices or
2. unions and structs (see below)
3. a vector for the states and a list for the parameters

The states (`y`) are always treated as vector, both on the **R** and the **C** level, but parameters (`p`) can also be passed down as lists and then split up at the **C** level. This can be tricky and requires some understanding of **R**'s data structures.

However, I recommend to start vectorization on the **R** level. **R** is quite fast with vectorized models, so the speedup may not compensate for the **C** programming effort. An example how to implement a vectorized predator-prey model can be found [here](https://github.com/tpetzoldt/dynamic-R-models/blob/master/02-predator-prey/lv-matrix.R).

Another idea is to use a code generator, so you may have a look at the CRAN package **rodeo** that creates fast Fortran code from equations formulated as tabular (i.e. LibreOffice or Excel) tables. Usage does not require kowledge of Fortran.

More about **rodeo** can be found in a paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.envsoft.2017.06.036) and the package documentation at https://dkneis.github.io/

If one really wants to program it in **C** here a small implementation of a Lotka-Volterra-Competition model [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) with 3 states. The parameters are handed over as parameter vector `p` at the C level while a `union` is used to improve readability:

```
/* file model.c */

#include <R.h>

union parvec {
  struct {
    double r[3], a[6];
  };
  double value[9];
} p;

/* initializer  */
void initmod(void (* odeparms)(int *, double *))
{
    int N = 9; /* total number of parameters */
    odeparms(&N, p.value);
}

/* Derivatives */
void derivs (int *neq, double *t, double *y, double *ydot,
             double *yout, int *ip) {

  double y_sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < *neq; i++) {
    y_sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < *neq; j++) y_sum += p.a[i + *neq * j] * y[j];
    ydot[i] = p.r[i] * y[i] * (1 - y_sum);
  }
}
```

And here the calling **R** code:

```r
# file call_model.R
library(deSolve)

system("R CMD SHLIB model.c")
dyn.load("model.dll")

p <- c(r = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.04), A = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2))
y <- c(X = c(2, 2, 2))
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 0.1)

out <- ode(y, times, func = "derivs", parms = p,
           dllname = "model", initfunc = "initmod")
matplot.0D(out)

dyn.unload("model.dll")
```

More elaborated solutions are possible, of course.

[image: Competition model with 3 equations in C]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the R code is perfect. I though I will reduce running time with the C wrap, if not I will use directly the R code.

Comment: Did you mean the R or the C code, or both? Or the linked [lv-matrix.R](https://github.com/tpetzoldt/dynamic-R-models/blob/master/02-predator-prey/lv-matrix.R)? Anyway, great that it helped you, even if "thank you" comments are sometimes considered as obsolete on StackOverflow, see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258032/3677576). The usual way is to click **accept**. The community sees then, that a question is answered. Later visitors have it easier to find relevant posts. Both, the answerer and you will then earn a little reward, but there is nevertheless no obligation to do so.

Comment: I have used the one in R, which is very helpfull with the parameters as list of arrays, now the problem is that it does not recognise the variables:
`
# SIR metapopulation model:
SIR <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
    dS = c()
    dI = c()
    dR = c()
    for(i in c(1:dim)){
      dS[i] <- delta_N[i]*(S[i]+I[i]+R[i])
      dI[i] <- 10
      dR[i] <- 10
    }
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  }) 
}
population <- c(S <- matrix(100,ncol=N,nrow =1 ), I <- matrix(10,ncol=N,nrow =1 ),
                R <- matrix(0,ncol=N,nrow =1 ))`

Comment: Please formulate this as a new question and provide reproducible code. You can also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65116698/3677576) with a similar question about a SIR model.