# How to implement a system of ODEs in desolve with C compiled code and changing parameter size

Tags: r, c, compiled, desolve

I am trying to implement a system of ODEs using the R package deSolve and compiled C code. I am using the recommendations provided with the following vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deSolve/vignettes/compiledCode.pdf.
In my model, I have one parameter for which I want to allocate the size dynamically.
The question was almost addressed in a previous thread [How to implement a system in deSolve, R, with N equations a N+m parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157263/how-to-implement-a-system-in-desolve-r-with-n-equations-a-nm-parameters).
More specifically I would like to declare the total size of the parameter vector as a parameter and not as a fixed value like it is done in the previous thread. Unfortunately, the compiler is not that happy with this option and I would like to know whether someone has any idea or hint on how to solve it.

For the example let me republish the one kindly published by @tpetzoldt in the previous thread and slightly modified to highlight my issue.

```
#include <R.h>
#define nA 6
#define nT 9

union parvec {
  struct {
    double r[3], a[nA];
  };
  double value[nT];
} p;

/* initializer  */
void initmod(void (* odeparms)(int *, double *))
{
    int N = nT; /* total number of parameters */
    odeparms(&N, p.value);
}

/* Derivatives */
void derivs (int *neq, double *t, double *y, double *ydot,
             double *yout, int *ip) {

  double y_sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < *neq; i++) {
    y_sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < *neq; j++) y_sum += p.a[i + *neq * j] * y[j];
    ydot[i] = p.r[i] * y[i] * (1 - y_sum);
  }
}
```

```
# file call_model.R
library(deSolve)

system("R CMD SHLIB model.c")
dyn.load("model.dll")

p <- c(r = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.04), A = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2))
y <- c(X = c(2, 2, 2))
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 0.1)

out <- ode(y, times, func = "derivs", parms = p,
           dllname = "model", initfunc = "initmod")
matplot.0D(out)

dyn.unload("model.dll")
```

I have looked at the vignette and specifically the section 3. Alternative way of passing parameters and data in compiled code but did succeed in solving my problem.

Comment: My main question is why someone wants to do this. Package deSolve was designed to be easy to use and as fast as possible, and if the model  function is implemented in C or Fortran,users should not need to implement an own memory management. Besides this, code compilation is nowadays very fast, so that a modified model with additional parameters or even state variables can be compiled on the fly. Code generators like **rodeo** or **odin** support this on a higher level, so why fiddling around with C pointers and `R_alloc`?